Validation Rule to Prompt User to Enter Products when NOT New throwing Flow errors
My validation rule is to prompt users to enter products upon EDIT after initial creation (as to not interrupt conversions). It works fine upon edit, but when creating a NEW opportunity using the NEW button or upon conversion it throws Flow errors. Why would this be when I have NOT (ISNEW()) in the formula?
AND(
NOT (ISNEW()),
RecordTypeId <> "0124R000001UuJaQAK",
RecordTypeId <> "0124R000001lGI6QAM",
No_Product_Lines__c =0
)

Just some thoughts, not knowing all the details: What do you mean it "throws Flow errors"? Did you address the flow error as well? It's possible that whatever that error is a flow is being encountered first, so the validation error doesn't get a chance to be triggered. Though I don't recall the order of operations in that regard. Also, not sure how you're populating the "No_Product_Lines__c" field, but if it is a rollup summary or  formula, it can sometimes be tricky to ensure the value evaluated is the one before the edit. Something to consider as you work through your problem

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include specific details on what you are doing.  What is being edited?  What is being created?  What is being converted?  What object is this validation rule for?  Please [edit] your post.

I believe you might be right about the order of operations on the flows that are set upon creation of an oppty. I'll check that out. I also tried using HasLineItems=False instead of my roll up of No_Product_Lines" but it still sends the flow error messages.
